# Is it a bad idea to create a library that only contains some mappers and related functions?

Tags: libraries, code-reuse

There is a software (once monolith) that makes use of a long list of mappers. You can think of them as Choices field, where each item translates into different conventions.
For ex, say that they are JSONs of all unit systems (weight, distance, storage, time, temperature etc) and their different standards (metric vs imperial) and representations (m, meters, Meters).

Right now the monolith is being split into services with very clearly-defined roles. One of the services serves the role of a central service. The list of mappers currently resides into the code base of this central service.

I was thinking of extracting them into a library, and add there some simple methods that given the name of the convention, would provide the necessary mapping. The library would be installed and used by any service that needs it.

The pros is obviously avoiding replications across services, or hard-coded values (which is happening right now).

The cons is that right now not many of the services use the mappers. I am unsure how this usability will evolve in the future.

Is it a bad practice or overkill to extract this functionality into a separate library?

Comment: Every new library starts with only a few bits of common functionality. So what objections do you have against this?

Comment: I don't think the length of the library matters. If you were familiar with NodeJS stack, you would realize how many libs depends on libs which source code is, no more and no less, a [single function](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/that-time-a-guy-broke-the-internet-23c00903ad6f)

Answer (score 2):

I think you may use not quite common wording.

Word "mapper" is usually used in cases when the values remain unchanged and only the structure or names change. For instance, you can map 3 objects like customer, product and order into a single object, which will then contain some fields from the customer object, some from the product, some from the order. Some of the attributes may become a combination of the others, like customer address consisting of many attributes may (city, zip, street, ...) may become a single attribute in another object. But original values are still recognizable.

In your case, unit systems (weight, distance, ...), system types (metric vs. imperial), it is better to speak about **converters**. A component that converts meters to yards or vice versa is usually called **converter**, not **mapper**.

**Mappers**, in the sense described above, are subject of change frequently, because changes in the structure of related objects often require also changes of mappers. That's why mappers are kept in the same module where they are used, e.g. in the same module as controller or REST service. Mappers are usually *not reusable* in other application parts.

**Converters**, in the sense described above, are usually independent on structure of any other objects, and it *may* well make sense to put them to a separate library. This can have following advantages:

- Development and testing can be done *independently* on the other application parts. This can allow more *stable and reliable* functionality of converters.
- If your company has further applications in the same business field, you can *reuse* these converters.

Comment: I know this question has been closed and don't expect an answer. However, I would like to clarify sth. The library would provide the representation of units. No conversion (or actual values) would be involved. So for ex, it would return the list of units of weight if the parameters would be 'weight' and 'SI', from the smallest to the largest. This list would later be used in forms where the user will fill in the numeric value of the weight and needs to chose from a predefined list of units of weight. 

So, I believe that 'mapper' is the correct word, or at least closer to it than 'converter'

Comment: @aws1785: I supposed you wanted to convert units from one system to another. If a service just returns the list of available units, then the proper name would be "master data".